# How to Activate AutoFormat so as to Activate Multiple Hyperlinks Simultaneously in Microsoft WORD for MAC

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, https, hyperlink

I've been able to find on the Web instructions for WORD 365 explaining how to replace all the URLs in a WORD document with corresponding active hyperlinks, by means of a single editing action. They are at:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-activate-multiple-hyperlinks-simultaneously/2d13084f-76ba-457e-a3c7-9cba02d61219

This is done by adding the AutoFormat command to the Quick Access Toolbar (QAT).

However I can't find how to achieve the equivalent effect in Microsoft WORD for Mac, which seems to have rather different menu commands and options.

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a Mac.

AutoFormat should work in the Mac, though.

In the Windows version, it is a tab on the AutoCorrect Options dialog.

Because I do not have a Mac, I cannot give better directions.

However, here is a [link to a template that has two QAT buttons for AutoFormat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpn1sr1zxi9b12g/AutoFormatQAT.dotx?dl=0) and should work on your Mac. If it downloads as a document, not as a .dotx file, save it as a .dotx file. The template contains instructions on how to use it.

It places two AutoFormat buttons on your Quick Access Toolbar (QAT).

Put the template in your [Word Startup Folder](http://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm). *This link is to my page*

Comment: ***Many*** thanks. Though I struggled a bit (for a start I had to find out what "QAT" meant) I managed to follow your instructions, and get Autoformat into the toolbar, and then to confirm that it successfully/magically activates the hundred or so URLs in a 45-page document of mine. Great!

Comment: Glad to have helped. I will try to clarify this for future readers. Did you use the template or did you add it directly yourself?

Comment: Hi Charles: I added it myself, once I'd found the Startup Folder. Being unfamiliar with WORD templates (and - as usual - getting little help from MS WORD for Mac's Help facilities), I did this rather blindly. Initially I was confused by your instruction: "To use this place it in your startup folder" -I  was not sure what "this" and "it" referred to. But somehow , in just a few minutes, I got the right item into the right place, found WORD now had an Autoformat command, and that this command processed my document  (containing about 180 URLs), first time exactly as I wanted. Thanks again.