# Applying "Autoformat Now" Word FOOTNOTES [Mac]

Tags: microsoft-word

Every week members of my team process documents that have like 300 links in footnotes in a Word document. Usually we add them manually by right clicking and interacting with the dialog box.

I discovered Autoformat, and that this can be added to the quick access toolbar. Yes, I have already seen this article: [How to Activate AutoFormat so as to Activate Multiple Hyperlinks Simultaneously in Microsoft WORD for MAC](https://superuser.com/questions/1713156/how-to-activate-autoformat-so-as-to-activate-multiple-hyperlinks-simultaneously).

That is great, but it does NOT format my footnote text. It will change links in the maintext but does nothing to the footnotes.

I'm on a Mac and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this doesn't work for footnotes. But you can use a VBA macro which copies each the text of each footnote to an empty document, autoformats it, and copies it back. This is a variation of code by Graham Mayor (http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?52466-applying-hyperlink-styles-in-footnotes-and-endnotes) which will work:

```
Sub LinkNotes()
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim oTemp As Document
Dim oNote As Range
Dim oFN As Footnote
Dim oRng As Range
Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
oDoc.Save
Set oTemp = Documents.Add(Template:=oDoc.FullName, Visible:=False)

For Each oFN In oDoc.Footnotes
    Set oNote = oFN.Range
    Set oRng = oTemp.Range
    oRng.FormattedText = oNote.FormattedText
    oRng.Style = "Footnote Text"
    Options.AutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks = True
    oRng.AutoFormat
    oRng.End = oRng.End - 1
    oNote.FormattedText = oRng.FormattedText
Next oFN
    
oTemp.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set oFN = Nothing
Set oDoc = Nothing
Set oTemp = Nothing
Set oRng = Nothing
Set oNote = Nothing
End Sub
```